# Cipher filter logstash 5.2

Tags: logstash

I'm using Logstash 5.2 and I need to encrypt some value from my log using chiper filter but unfortunately i get this error.

```
bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-filter-cipher
Validating logstash-filter-cipher
Installing logstash-filter-cipher
Plugin version conflict, aborting
ERROR: Installation Aborted, message: Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "logstash-core-plugin-api":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    logstash-core-plugin-api (= 2.1.12)

  In Gemfile:
    logstash-devutils (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 2.0) java

    logstash-input-s3 (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-mixin-aws (>= 0) java depends on
        logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java
```

the error continues till it says

```
Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "logstash":
  In Gemfile:
    logstash-filter-cipher (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash (< 2.0.0, >= 1.4.0) java
Could not find gem 'logstash (< 2.0.0, >= 1.4.0) java', which is required by gem 'logstash-filter-cipher (>= 0) java', in any of the sources.
```

I don't understand if this problem is about chiper filter that is not supported yet or I'm doing something wrong..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gem has not yet been updated to support versions of Logstash newer than the 2.x series. Your clue is in the bundler output:

```
In Gemfile:
  logstash-filter-cipher (>= 0) java depends on
    logstash (< 2.0.0, >= 1.4.0) java
```

Running logstash 2.4 will likely work better for you.

Comment: true, is not compatible yet...what options do I have in logstash for encrypting specific fields?